# Accept a character from console and display its next character

Tags: go

I want to write a program that accepts a character from console and display its next character.

This is what I tried:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var ch int32
    fmt.Printf("Enter Char : ")
    fmt.Scan(&ch)

    ch++

    fmt.Printf("Next Char is %s ", string(ch))

}
```

Comment: Duplicate. string(ch) does **NOT** do what you think it does. Take the Tour of Go once more. To print a character: Use the `%c` verb in fmt.Printf (instead of %s) and do not try to typeconvert to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Characters" in Go are called *runes*, and `rune` is an alias for `int32`. You need two changes:

1. Scan with the proper verb (your `Scan` actually fails - check for errors!)
2. Print with the proper verb

Here's an extended example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {

    var ch rune
    fmt.Printf("Enter Char : ")
    _, err := fmt.Scanf("%c", &ch)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("ch = %x\n", ch)
    ch++
    fmt.Printf("ch+1 = %x\n", ch)
    fmt.Printf("Next char is %c\n", ch)
}
```

Sample session:

```
Enter Char : a
ch = 61
ch+1 = 62
Next char is b
```

Make sure to read [this official Go blog post](https://blog.golang.org/strings) to better understand how runes and strings interact.

Comment: thank you @Eli Bendersky. this example help me a lot to understand this concept